# LED typical and forward voltages

Tags: voltage, led, diodes, resistance, semiconductors

So, I was going through the [spec sheet](http://pcboard.ca/leds-and-led-ribbon/leds/5mm-leds/5mm-super-bright-orange.html) of super bright 5mm orange LED, and it was listed that the forward voltage is between 1.8V and 2.5V. Below that there was a property listed as 'typical voltage' and had a value of 3.2V. I'm confused as to what value of resistance I must use.

Comment: Provide said spec sheet please.

Comment: Here ya go : http://pcboard.ca/leds-and-led-ribbon/leds/5mm-leds/5mm-super-bright-orange.html

Comment: Yeah. Strange. Perhaps they mean typical circuit voltage, this LED is used in?

Comment: Okay. But if that's so what's the relevance of such a value?

Comment: Looks like an error on the page,  if you ask me. Because the data for the white one looks ok

Comment: I think it should read 2.3 instead of 3.2.

Answer (score 2):

The important thing to realize is that CURRENT is what MATTERS to an LED. The voltage is given as a range because the voltage varies, depending on manufacturing tolerances, temperature, etc.

If you design well for LEDs, you feed them with a current source, and the voltage simply needs to be adequate for the number of LEDs you have in series on each current source. In figuring the voltage compliance your current source should have, look at the highest voltage quoted.

If you use resistors for current-limiting LEDs, use either the LOWEST value of forward voltage provided, or a bit less than that (safety margin) when choosing a resistor to set the current. This is sub-optimal .vs. a current source, as it will generally be providing less than the maximum safe current in order not to provide more than the maximum safe current under conditions (or for parts) where the forward voltage is particularly low.

Comment: Using a current source for LEDs is totally overkill for many applications. Using resistors is just fine for indicators.

Comment: ...where sub-optimal is just fine, being merely an indicator. I didn't say it was wrong, I said it was sub-optimal - and it is, if looking for maximum safe output.

Answer (score 1):

Quick solution. If you want to know the forward voltage hook your LED to a power supply turned down to 0 volts and slowly crank up the voltage.

You LED will turn on once forward voltage is reached.

**However**, you might blow an LED up doing this so proceed with caution.

To help answer your question. Use forward current to decide on what resistor to use and take the worst case forward voltage.

Comment: It's a pretty bad suggestion... no current limiting? Come on..

Comment: @EugeneSh. Never had a problem with current draw, and very helpful when your LEDs get jumbled up. But like I said, its risky.

Comment: Always use a resistor in series.

Comment: I think it's a bad idea. Once the threshold is reached, even for a slight increase in voltage, the current levels will increase unprecedentedly.

Comment: The power supply proposal is more realistic if you have a lab supply that has variable voltage and variable current limit. Set the voltage to say 4 volts and start with the current set to 0. Connect the LED in forward bias mode and carefully increase the current limit up to allow current to flow to the LED.

Comment: @MichaelKaras I agree that would be useful for finding forward current but not forward voltage. I think if you want to be safe about not damaging your LEDs you could set the current limit to the forward current on your power supply.

Comment: @JakeRobinson - My bench supply works pretty nice as I described. It has digital meters on it that show current and voltage. As the current is increased the meter on the supply is showing the voltage across its terminals at the same time. You can crank up current to desired level and directly read out the LED voltage.

Comment: @MichaelKaras O nice, well in that case sounds good. Your description made it sound like you could not read back the voltage  after setting it to 4.

Comment: @JakeRobinson - Well if the lab supply had no volt meter it would stand to reason that if trying to measure LED forward voltage you would have a DVM hooked up.....right?

Comment: @MichaelKaras If that is what you are trying to do then yes.

Answer (score 1):

If you have doubts on the stated specs, you can make a simple Constant Current regulator to test an LED out with a common adjustable LDO.

[image]

R1 can be a fixed resistor, or more conveniently, a variable resistor or trimpot. For 20 mA, that's 62.5 Ω. (R = V/I, in this case VRef / IOut).

Simply measure the voltage across the Load/LED and you know how much it's Forward Voltage Drop at 20mA is.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea. A constant current source will always come in handy.

Comment: A small doubt though.. What's the cap used here for..

Comment: @user4493465 filtering the input. Use whatever cap is recommended by the regulator you use. It may be 1~100 uF instead.